# $.ajax is not going into the SUCCESS but is successful

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this bit of code below:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: headers,
        //async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
        dataType: 'json',
        //cache: false,
        //data: formData,
        encode: true
    }).success(function (data) {
        //data = data.substring(5, 5000);
        //myObj = $.parseJSON(data);

        console.log("Data coming back from the server: ", data);

        if (data === 0) {
            $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
            //Reset form after success
            $("#contact-form")[0].reset();
            $('.error').fadeOut(500);
        } else {
            $('.error').fadeIn(1000);
            $("#contact-form")[0].reset();
            $('.success').fadeOut(500);
        }
        //clear all fields
        $('#contact-form').trigger("reset");

    }).error(function (e, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        console.log("Status: ", textStatus);
        console.log("JQXHR: ", xhr);

    }).done(function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

        //Reset formData
        formData = {
            "f": null,
            "e": null,
            "p": null,
            "m": null,
            "b": null,
            "d": null,
            "i": null

        };
        console.log('AJAX COMPLETE', data, textStatus, xhr);
    });
```

Everything is great but where it goes is DIRECTLY into the .ERROR() NOT the .SUCCESS but the form "IS" successful with status of 200 and text of OK.

What I'm trying to figure out and this is probably really simple, is why it's NOT going into the SUCCESS function and dropping through to the ERROR FUNCTION but is "SUCCESSFUL" as I get the email that's sent perfectly.

Thank you in advance.

AT THIS POINT in the code, as I step...

It's bypassed .success, data is undefined and it's now on the .error line

```
    }).success(function (data) {
        //data = data.substring(5, 5000);
        //myObj = $.parseJSON(data);

        console.log("Data coming back from the server: ", data);

        if (data === 0) {
            $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
            //Reset form after success
            $("#contact-form")[0].reset();
            $('.error').fadeOut(500);
        } else {
            $('.error').fadeIn(1000);
            $("#contact-form")[0].reset();
            $('.success').fadeOut(500);
        }
        //clear all fields
        $('#contact-form').trigger("reset");

    }).error(function (e, textStatus, xhr) { <- CODE IS HERE and then goes in
        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        console.log("Status: ", textStatus);
        console.log("JQXHR: ", xhr);

        **//textStatus = OK
        //response = 200**

    }).done(function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
```

Comment: What is the error message? Are you returning valid json? Also why do you have `jsonpCallback` set?

Comment: What does the error that you're logging say?

Comment: Yes. What I'm returning is a ZERO or 1. I'm sending off to EMAIL as the formData contains the FORM information. So, I simply need to return a 1 = SUCCESS or 0 = ERROR. Hence, why I have if(data === 0), just checked the RETURN value in JSON and it's a ZERO ('0')

Comment: There's no error! Nothing! the dev console is CLEAN!  REALLY!

Comment: I'm using JQUERY 3.0.0

Comment: As @charlietfl mentioned, why do you have a `jsonpCallback` set if all you are returning is a `0` or `1`?  It may be erroring because it can't find that function in the response.

Comment: OK, I'm an IDIOT! I had comments so I could see what was coming into the PHP and POOF! When I commented them out, which PARSEERROR told me what I needed, everything works GREAT!  But yes, Charlieffi and Jmoerdyk you were BOTH correct. I removed the JSONPCALLBACK as well.  Move your statement to a combined SOLUTION and I'll vote it as correct and +1.  THANKS for helping everyone.

Comment: Notice, that the comment I made offended Renato and note what he removed from the above comments that I put in as a solution. COMPLIMENTING you folks is "GROUNDS" for editing and REDACTING and DOWN VOTING. Hmmmm. Democracy or ....

Answer (score -1):

I had comments so I could see what was coming into the PHP and POOF! When I commented them out, which PARSEERROR told me what I needed, everything works GREAT! But yes, Charlieffi and Jmoerdyk you were BOTH correct. I removed the JSONPCALLBACK as well. Move your statement to a combined SOLUTION and I'll vote it as correct and +1.

Comment: Renato. __________ for editing. Was only trying to condescending to myself and I didn't USE vulgarity.  And I didn't think _______ PEOPLE was grounds for a DOWN VOTE and removal from my comments.  But, I'm not the boss and therefore I SHALL REFRAIN from any form of compliments and try to only be VAGUE and BENIGN.  Please feel free to down vote more.